# Listing all posts from current category on page

Tags: categories, pages, loop, array, list

I'm trying to list all posts from a certain category, in a list, on the category page that already lists the posts out in blog form. I'm trying to do it in the header area so that you can get an overall look at the posts on the page. I found this:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

But it always seems to cut one of the posts out of the list. Is there an easier way to do this, without a plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! I think you're making things harder for yourself than they need to be. If I understand your question, you're looking for [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts). The always useful *Digging Into WordPress* has [a nice summary of it](http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/#rewind_posts).

Because both tasks involve looping through the *same query*, you don't need `get_posts()` at all.

Instead, you'll want to use the aforementioned `rewind_posts()` something like this:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
<!-- Your list of posts -->
<ul>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php rewind_posts(); // second <del>verse</del> query, same as the first ?>

<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- your "blog-style" stuff -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks, I'll look into how rewind_posts works a little more as well.