# List ALL posts within last week from current category on category page

Tags: wp-query, loop

My category template shows 5 (full content) posts per page and I want to add a **list of ALL the posts during the past week for that category to the top of the page as a quick overview.** So the first post in the list will be same as first full-content post below the list, etc. except the overview list can have more than 5 posts.

I found [this similar answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51342/listing-all-posts-from-current-category-on-page) but it would only show 5 items at a time too, since that is my default posts per page setting.

I also tried using this code, but it shows posts from all categories. I only want to include the current category.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'date_query'     => array(
                            array(
                            'after' => '1 week ago'
                            )
                        )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<ul>';

    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $post -> ID ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

    }

    echo '</ul>';

}
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you just need two more arguments in your `$args` array.

Firstly, `category_name` - see [WP_Query - Category Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). We get the value from the `$wp_query` global via [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var), so like this:

```
'category_name' => get_query_var( 'category_name' )
```

Secondly, for the number of posts to show there is `posts_per_page` as it is an archive one could actually use `posts_per_archive_page` - see [WP_Query - Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

So do either:

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

Or do:

```
'posts_per_archive_page' => -1
```

Comment: You are a genius. You were able to read my mind and you nailed the answer. Works perfectly.